# Erro ao carregar partialView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal

Eu estou com um problema meio curioso. Criei uma página que lista registros e ela tem dois links, um para excluir e outro pra exibir detalhes. Ambos chamam uma modal. Cada modal, é uma `partialView`. A `partialview` que exibe a modal de exclusão está na página list, e a `partialView` que exibe a modal dos detalhes, está na view_layout.

O meu problema é o seguinte: uma anula a outra. A modal até é exibida, vai na base, mas não exibe os dados.
Quando eu comento qualquer uma das `partialView`, a outra funciona.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Coloque trechos do código que realizam ação que você deseja assim ficará mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo....

Comment: Poste trecho de código para que os usuários possam te ajudar. Provavelmente pode ser erro de Id ou name.